NavigationMixin.Navigate to recordPage doesn't update record with defaultFieldValues
I want to update Account record through LWC component with predefined values in defaultFieldValues for NavigationMixin.Navigate, standard__recordPage. It shows new default values correctly when edit window pops up but once I save the record it doesn't change the values.
Here is more about encodedDefaultFieldValuesString method. Basically returns values as strings.

this.recordWrapper = {
            "BillingCity": this.gusData.city,
            "BillingPostalCode": this.gusData.zipCode,
            "BillingState": this.gusData.province,
            "BillingStreet": this.updateBillingStreet(),
            "BillingCountry": this.gusData.country,
            "GUS_NIP__c": this.gusData.nip,
            "Name": this.gusData.name,
        };

navigateToRecordEditPage() {
        console.log('recordId ' + this.recordId);
        console.log('record type ' + this.objectType);
        console.log('record values ' + encodeDefaultFieldValues(this.recordWrapper));
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__recordPage",
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: this.objectType,
                actionName: "edit"
            },
            state: {
                defaultFieldValues: encodeDefaultFieldValues(this.recordWrapper)
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('@@ error test' + error.message);
        });
    }

Values in logs are correct. There are no errors. I already checked field level security and ensured current user has access to these fields. I also disabled every flow that was launching automatically on Account object. There are no triggers, process builders or workflow rules on that object.

Please show how this.recordWrapper is defined and show what "encodeDefaultFieldValues" does. Please [edit] the question to add these details.

Sure. Updated with more info.

The cause of it in our case was enabled dynamic forms. We found it worked fine in app without dynamic forms enabled on the same object page. The issue was reported to Salesforce and they recognized it as a bug on their side. I'm not working in that project anymore so can't confirm if it's already resolved.

Issue:
I encountered the same problem Jacob was facing where the WhatId was not persisting after saving a record, despite being visible in the Apex debug logs.
Description:
After some painful time wrapping my head around this problem, I discovered that while using the encodeURIComponent method allowed me to see the WhatId in the debug logs, it did not solve the persistence issue upon saving the record.
Resolution:
To resolve this, I had to explicitly add an Assignment element to the Task Before Flow to set WhatId equal to WhatId.
Which resolved the Issue.
Have shared the code Snippet Below for Reference.


In our case it was caused by dynamic forms. It worked on the same object in different app without dynamic forms enabled. We reported it to Salesforce and they confirmed it was a bug on their side. I guess it's still not resolved.
